# Regular Expression To Select An Entire Line That Contains a HTML Class

Tags: html, regex, textmate

I'm using TextMate to edit a project that I'm doing(HTML files) and I have some `<div>` tags assigned with the `class=navigation` property, but I need to change this `<div>`'s for a new design that I'm planning, but they are much(about 47 results if I search for `class=navigation`).

So I need a regular expression to match the entire line that this property is found, but which is it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not a regex expert, but I would think that `^.*class=navigation.*$` would work.

Comment: But . should be greedy and even match the class=navigation string, no?